# Linux pseudo directory triggers the error "no such file or directory"

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

### Summary

I'm creating a pseudo filesystem for Linux kernel 4.13, but my directories can't be listed with `ls`.  I keep getting the message:

```
ls: cannot access 'mountedfs/data': No such file or directory.
```

### Details

Creation and registration of the `super_block` and root `dentry` structures goes well.  I can mount the file system without trouble, but I can't list the contents of my filesystem.  When I try I get the error "No such file or directory".

After creating the `super_block` and root `dentry`, I call `womfs_create_files()` to populate the tree.  Here is the full source code of the module.  As you can see, I haven't even bothered with the file operations yet.  I'm still stuck on inode operations.

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>       /* libfs and most file-related headers. */
#include <linux/dcache.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/pagemap.h>  /* PAGE_SIZE */
#include <linux/atomic.h>
#include <linux/time.h>
#include <linux/string.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/parser.h>
#include <linux/magic.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>
#include "wombat.h"
/*
 *  Wombat directories are all basic.  They just contain stuff, you can't link to them,
 *  you can't delete them, and you can't modify them.  Anyone can list them, and
 *  they're owned by root.
 *
 *  The file inodes are more specialized: they have to be linked to information about the
 *  keys they represent and the operations that can be performed on those keys.
 *  The same key data will be used by several inodes, but each inode needs to understand
 *  its particular purpose.  (eg: "<key>/pub_key" lets you retrieve the public key;
 *  "<key>/sign" lets you sign data with the key.)
 *
 *  Open file nodes need state information for processing reads, writes, ioctl,
 *  etc..
 */

/*
 * Boilerplate stuff.
 */
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("CJ Holmes");

#define WOMFS_NAME "womfs"
#define WOMFS_MAGIC 0x00ff0019 // Lear Red

/*
 * Operations keygen file that uses the machine-specific KEK to create
 * a shrouded key for data encryption.
 */

int womfs_keygen_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{
    return 0;
}

ssize_t womfs_keygen_read(struct file *filp, char __user *buf,
        size_t count, loff_t *offset)
{
  return 0;
}

int womfs_keygen_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{
  return 0;
}

static struct file_operations keygen_ops = {
  .open = womfs_keygen_open,
  .release = womfs_keygen_release,
  .read = womfs_keygen_read,
};

/*
 *  Operations for encryption endpoints.  The key and semantics depend on
 *  the key info in i_private and calls to ioctl.
 */

int womfs_encrypt_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{
  return 0;
}

ssize_t womfs_encrypt_read(struct file *filp, char *buf,
        size_t count, loff_t *offset)
{
   return 0;
}

ssize_t womfs_encrypt_write(struct file *filp, const char __user * buf, size_t len, loff_t *pos) {
    return 0;
}

int womfs_encrypt_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{
   return 0;
}

long womfs_encrypt_ioctl(struct file *filp, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long data)
{
   return 0;
}

static struct file_operations encrypt_ops = {
  .open = womfs_encrypt_open,
  .release = womfs_encrypt_release,
  .read = womfs_encrypt_read,
  .write = womfs_encrypt_write,
  .unlocked_ioctl = womfs_encrypt_ioctl,
};

/*
 *  Stuff for building our FS structure.
 */

// Implementation borrowed from fs/stat.c:vsf_getattr_nosec()
int womfs_getattr(const struct path *path, struct kstat *stat, u32 request_mask,
    unsigned int query_flags) {
        struct inode *inode;

        inode = d_inode(path->dentry);
        printk(KERN_WARNING WOMFS_NAME " womfs_getattr(%pd4) --> %p\n", path->dentry, inode);

        memset(stat, 0, sizeof(*stat));
        stat->result_mask |= STATX_BASIC_STATS;
        if(inode != NULL)
            generic_fillattr(inode, stat); // fs/stat.c
        return 0;
}

const struct inode_operations womfs_dir_inode_operations = {
    .lookup     = simple_lookup,
    .getattr  = womfs_getattr,
};

const struct inode_operations womfs_inode_operations = {
    .getattr = womfs_getattr,
};

 static struct inode *womfs_make_inode(struct super_block *sb, struct wombat_key_info *key,
   kgid_t group, char *domain, int mode, struct file_operations *fops)
{
    struct inode *ret = new_inode(sb);
    struct timespec now = current_kernel_time();

    if (ret) {
        ret->i_mode = mode;
        ret->i_uid = KUIDT_INIT(0);
        ret->i_gid = group;
        ret->i_blocks = 0;
        ret->i_atime = now;
        ret->i_mtime = now;
        ret->i_ctime = now;

    if (mode & S_IFDIR) {
      ret->i_op = &womfs_dir_inode_operations;
      ret->i_fop = (fops == NULL) ? &simple_dir_operations : fops ;
      inc_nlink(ret);
    } else {
            ret->i_op = &womfs_inode_operations;
      ret->i_fop = fops;
    }

    ret->i_private = key;
  }

  return ret;
}


struct dentry *womfs_add_node_to_dir(struct dentry *parent, struct inode *node, const char *name)
{
  struct dentry *child;
  struct qstr qname;

  qname.name = name;
  qname.len = strlen(name);
  qname.hash = full_name_hash(NULL, name, qname.len);

  child = d_alloc(parent, &qname);
  if (child != NULL)
  {
        // d_instantiate(child, node);
    d_add(child, node);
        inode_inc_link_count(node);
  }

  return child;
}


static void womfs_create_files (struct super_block *sb, struct dentry *root)
{
  struct dentry *subdir;
  struct dentry *fentry;
  struct inode *node;
  kgid_t group;

  /*  This will eventually be a loop through all of the slots provided by the SNVS.
      For now, we can just add the KEK entry. */

  struct wombat_key_info *ki = kzalloc(sizeof(struct wombat_key_info), GFP_KERNEL);
  ki->type = wombat_key_kek;
  ki->slot = 0;
  strcpy(ki->name, "data");
  // leave group and domain blank, pending further implementation.
  group = KGIDT_INIT(0);

  /*  This can be cleaned up, perhaps by combining womfs_make_inode()
      and womfs_add_node_to_dir()
  */
  node = womfs_make_inode(sb, ki, group, NULL, S_IFDIR | 0555, NULL);
  if(node != NULL) {

    subdir = womfs_add_node_to_dir(root, node, ki->name);
    if (subdir != NULL) {
      printk(KERN_WARNING WOMFS_NAME " %pd4", subdir);
      switch(ki->type) {
        case wombat_key_kek:
          /* create the data/keygen file */
          node = womfs_make_inode(sb, ki, group, NULL, S_IFREG | 0444, &keygen_ops);
          if(node != NULL) {
            fentry = womfs_add_node_to_dir(subdir, node, "keygen");
            if(fentry != NULL)
              printk(KERN_WARNING WOMFS_NAME " %pd4", fentry);
            else
              iput(node);
          }
          /*  create the data/encrypt file */
          node = womfs_make_inode(sb, ki, group, NULL, S_IFREG | 0666, &encrypt_ops);
          if( node != NULL) {
            fentry = womfs_add_node_to_dir(subdir, node, "encrypt");
            if(fentry != NULL)
              printk(KERN_WARNING WOMFS_NAME " %pd4", fentry);
            else
              iput(node);
          }
          break;
        default:
          /* Show some error here. */
          break;
      }
    } else {
      iput(node);
    }
  }
}

/*
 * Superblock stuff.  This is all boilerplate to give the vfs something
 * that looks like a filesystem to work with.
 */

/*
 * Our superblock operations, both of which are generic kernel ops
 * that we don't have to write ourselves.
 */
static struct super_operations womfs_s_ops = {
    .statfs     = simple_statfs,
    .drop_inode = generic_delete_inode,
};

/*
 * "Fill" a superblock with mundane stuff.
 */
static int womfs_fill_super (struct super_block *sb, void *data, int silent)
{
  int retval = 0;
    struct inode *root = NULL;
    struct dentry *root_dentry = NULL;
  kgid_t gid = KGIDT_INIT(0);

  /*
   * Basic parameters.
   */
    sb->s_blocksize = PAGE_SIZE;
    sb->s_blocksize_bits = PAGE_SHIFT;
    sb->s_magic = WOMFS_MAGIC;
    sb->s_op = &womfs_s_ops;
  sb->s_time_gran = 1;

/*
 * We need to conjure up an inode to represent the root directory
 * of this filesystem.  Its operations all come from libfs, so we
 * don't have to mess with actually *doing* things inside this
 * directory.
 */

  root = womfs_make_inode(sb, NULL, gid, NULL, S_IFDIR | 0555, NULL);
    if (root != NULL) {

    // make the root directory entry.
    root_dentry = d_make_root(root);
    if (root_dentry != NULL) {
      sb->s_root = root_dentry;
      womfs_create_files (sb, root_dentry);
      printk(KERN_WARNING WOMFS_NAME " setup complete\n");
    } else {
      retval = -ENOMEM;
    }
  } else {
    retval = -ENOMEM;
  }

  if (retval != 0) {
    // clean up our inode and dirent
    if (root != NULL) {
      iput(root);
    }
    if (root_dentry != NULL) {
      dput(root_dentry);
    }
  }

    return retval;
}


/*
 * Stuff to pass in when registering the filesystem.
 */
struct dentry *womfs_mount(struct file_system_type *fst,
        int flags, const char *devname, void *data)
{
    return mount_nodev(fst, flags, data, womfs_fill_super);
}


static struct file_system_type womfs_type = {
    .owner    = THIS_MODULE,
    .name         = WOMFS_NAME,
    .mount    = womfs_mount,
    .kill_sb    = kill_litter_super,
};


/*
 * Get things set up.
 */
static int __init womfs_init(void)
{
    return register_filesystem(&womfs_type);
}

static void __exit womfs_exit(void)
{
    unregister_filesystem(&womfs_type);
}

module_init(womfs_init);
module_exit(womfs_exit);
```

When I load the module and mount my filesystem, I see the following lines in my syslog:

```
Apr 17 11:43:59 felix kernel: [ 7024.360872] womfs data
Apr 17 11:43:59 felix kernel: [ 7024.360873] womfs data/keygen
Apr 17 11:43:59 felix kernel: [ 7024.360874] womfs data/encrypt
Apr 17 11:43:59 felix kernel: [ 7024.360875] womfs setup complete
```

The `ls` command shows my mounted file system:

```
cholmes@felix:~/leardev/womfs$ ls -l
total 668
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cholmes cholmes    317 Apr 12 10:38 Makefile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cholmes cholmes     46 Apr 17 11:28 modules.order
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cholmes cholmes      0 Apr 16 15:50 Module.symvers
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cholmes cholmes   6860 Apr 12 11:39 README.md
    ... etc ...
dr-xr-xr-x 2 root    root         0 Apr 17 11:28 mountedfs
```

But listing the contents of `mountedfs` is a disaster:

```
cholmes@felix:~/leardev/wombat$ ls -l mountedfs
ls: cannot access 'mountedfs/data': No such file or directory
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? data
```

It seems obvious I'm forgetting something pretty simple.  It just isn't obvious to **me** yet.

### Update 1

The `data` directory uses `simple_dir_inode_operations` and `simple_dir_operations` pointers from `libfs`.

The two regular files have very minimal ops structures, but I'll post them after I remove all the truly interesting bits ;-)

An `strace ls -l mountedfs` command displays:

```
... all the usual linking to run ls ...
open("mountedfs/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
getdents(3, /* 3 entries */, 32768)     = 72
lstat("mountedfs/data", 0xaa01a0)       = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
... the rest is all about printing the error message ...
```

### Update 2

The missing `getattr()` hook doesn't seem to be the problem.  VFS provides a default implementation that copies attribute information from the inode, so you don't really need to implement `getattr()` unless you have to deal with syncing to disk or similar issues.

What I discovered was that my getattr() methods aren't even being called for subdirectories.  Here's the new bits of my implementation:

```
// Implementation borrowed from fs/stat.c:vsf_getattr_nosec()
int womfs_getattr(const struct path *path, struct kstat *stat, u32 request_mask,
    unsigned int query_flags) {
        struct inode *inode;

        inode = d_inode(path->dentry);
        printk(KERN_WARNING WOMFS_NAME " womfs_getattr(%pd4) --> %p\n", path->dentry, inode);

        memset(stat, 0, sizeof(*stat));
        stat->result_mask |= STATX_BASIC_STATS;
        if(inode != NULL)
            generic_fillattr(inode, stat); // fs/stat.c
        return 0;
}

const struct inode_operations womfs_dir_inode_operations = {
    .lookup     = simple_lookup,
    .getattr  = womfs_getattr,
};

const struct inode_operations womfs_inode_operations = {
    .getattr = womfs_getattr,
};
```

I add these ops to the inodes in the expected way.  When I mount my file system I get `printk()` messages as expected:

```
Apr 18 14:19:21 felix kernel: [20777.116214] womfs /data
Apr 18 14:19:21 felix kernel: [20777.116216] womfs /data/keygen
Apr 18 14:19:21 felix kernel: [20777.116217] womfs /data/encrypt
Apr 18 14:19:21 felix kernel: [20777.116218] womfs setup complete
```

And when I do an `ls` on the filesystem I get the same error message as before, plus some syslog messages telling me that `womfs_getattr()` was invoked.

```
Apr 18 14:19:27 felix kernel: [20782.880473] womfs womfs_getattr(/) --> ffff9e957c902960
Apr 18 14:19:27 felix kernel: [20782.880696] womfs womfs_getattr(/) --> ffff9e957c902960
```

So only the root of the filesystem is being stat'ed.  It seems like my inode isn't being properly added to the dentry.

After reading more examples, I switched out my call to `d_add()` with `d_instantiate()` instead.  Now the error messsage is gone, but the file system shows as being empty:

```
cholmes@felix:~/leardev/wombat$ ls -l mountedfs/
total 0
```

And now my syslog shows 5 accesses:

```
 Apr 18 14:45:06 felix kernel: [22321.799115] womfs womfs_getattr(/) --> ffff9e95f95a04b0
 Apr 18 14:45:06 felix kernel: [22321.800553] womfs womfs_getattr(/) --> ffff9e95f95a04b0
 Apr 18 14:45:06 felix kernel: [22321.800554] womfs womfs_getattr(/) --> ffff9e95f95a04b0
 Apr 18 14:45:06 felix kernel: [22322.406112] womfs womfs_getattr(/) --> ffff9e95f95a04b0
 Apr 18 14:45:06 felix kernel: [22322.406341] womfs womfs_getattr(/) --> ffff9e95f95a04b0
```

And strace says:

```
open("mountedfs/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
getdents(3, /* 2 entries */, 32768)     = 48
getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(3)                                = 0
```

At this point I'm completely confused and just trying semi-random things to see what will happen.

Comment: What are your ops (array with function pointers)? In current form this is not easy to answer, as we can't reproduce your setup and get same error. You may start from `strace ls -l` to get name of failed syscall and exact error code, then check corresponding ops in vfs and in your fs. Some kernel-level tracing (ftrace / trace-cmd) may help. Check this example with readdir: https://github.com/krinkinmu/aufs/blob/master/kern/dir.c `const struct file_operations aufs_dir_ops = ... .iterate = aufs_readdir,` or http://www.geocities.ws/ravikiran_uvs/articles/rkfs.html for `readdir` file op

Comment: `ls` was able to get name `data`, but not stat ([syscall stat](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html), size, date, uid, gid, mode, a/m/ctime ...) info about the directory inode. Did you implement any method to fill `struct kstat`? Like `fuse_fillattr` https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.18/source/fs/fuse/dir.c#L891 / `fuse_do_getattr` which is indirectly referenced from `struct inode_operations ... .getattr = fuse_getattr,`

Comment: please add new strace log for the case of "`$ ls -l mountedfs/
total 0`"

Comment: In the case where I use d_instantiate I get no errors from `ls`.  The strace output has been fixed (I added the wrong output before.)

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> wombat$ ls -l mountedfs
> ls: cannot access 'mountedfs/data': No such file or directory
> total 0
> d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? data
> ```

`ls` output like this shows subdirectory name but not shows file mode, uid, gid or date/time. This can be when there was some correct syscall to return directory name; and where was another syscall to get additional information about inode, which had failed.

You should to check `strace ls -l` output to get exact syscall names and return values, but I think there was [`readdir`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readdir.2.html)/[`getdents`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getdents.2.html) to read `data` and there was failed [`stat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) (stat64, fstat, lstat, ...)

In your code you set fops for the inode (of directory type) in this fragment:

```
   if (mode & S_IFDIR) {
     ret->i_op = &simple_dir_inode_operations;
     ret->i_fop = &simple_dir_operations;
```

But simple file/inode operations have not any method defined to provide stat implementation:

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4/source/fs/libfs.c#L189

```
const struct file_operations simple_dir_operations = {
    .open       = dcache_dir_open,
    .release    = dcache_dir_close,
    .llseek     = dcache_dir_lseek,
    .read       = generic_read_dir,
    .iterate    = dcache_readdir,
    .fsync      = noop_fsync,
};

const struct inode_operations simple_dir_inode_operations = {
    .lookup     = simple_lookup,
};
```

I think, `getattr` field of `struct inode_operations` is for implementing `stat`. Without implementation (with simple_inode_operations) stat syscall can't fill any useful data into `struct kstat`.

Some examples of getattr: [fuse_getattr](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4/ident/fuse_getattr) in [fs/fuse/dir.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4/source/fs/fuse/dir.c#L1710), http://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/~crwth/programming/VFS/inodes.php, https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-8.html ...

Documentation: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/vfs.txt

```
struct inode_operations

    int (*getattr) (const struct path *, struct kstat *, u32, unsigned int);

  getattr: called by the VFS to get attributes of a file. This method
    is called by stat(2) and related system calls.
```

`ls` sources https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/ls.c to prove that invalid return code of stat leads to `ls: cannot access` message

```
/* If true, the file listing format requires that stat be called on
   each file.  */
...
format_needs_stat =  ... || format == long_format || ...
...
 dereference = ... DEREF_NEVER;
...
gobble_file (char const *name, enum filetype type, ino_t inode,
...
if ( ... || format_needs_stat  || ...) {
...
        default: /* DEREF_NEVER */
          err = lstat (full_name, &f->stat);
          do_deref = false;
          break;
        }

      if (err != 0)
        {
          /* Failure to stat a command line argument leads to
             an exit status of 2.  For other files, stat failure
             provokes an exit status of 1.  */
          file_failure (command_line_arg,
                        _("cannot access %s"), full_name);
```

Comment: I don't know how I managed not to find and bookmark the vfs.txt document before -- especially as it is sitting in my linux source tree!  I'll post the solution when I have it coded.

Comment: un-marked as the answer, because this doesnn't seem to be the problem.  See the updates to the question.  Still working on it...

Comment: @slashingweapon, Why -15? Where is the new `strace`  output and updated sources? Why don't use ftrace / trace-cmd (or even lttng) tracers to get more info about what was called and when? It is not magic to call getattr; it is `ls` doing stat and vfs implementing stat. (You may also start from fuse examples...)

Comment: I just unmarked this answer as the solution, because getattr() doesn't seem to be the problem.  If I turn out to be wrong then I'll restore it.  It really seems like the inode data isn't being retained by the dentry.  The dentry is there and has a name, but the inode data is missing.  I have updated the code in the OP to be more complete.